# Is non-eigenvector still non-eigenvector after polynomial transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Give square matrix $A$, if vector $x$ is not in the eigenspace of $A$, then there won't be a  polynomial $f(x) = a_0+a_1x+..+a_nx^n$ such that $f(A)x=kx$?

- example:

$B = \begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\ 0&1
\end{pmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $1, 1$, and only one eigenvector $x_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 0
\end{pmatrix}$, so

$x_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}$ is not in the eigenspace of $B$, is there any polynomial $f(x)$ satisfying $f(x_2)=kx_2$?

Comment: Let $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$ and $x=\pmatrix{1\\ 0}$. Then $Ax$ is not parallel to $x$ but $A^2x=x$.

Comment: @user1551 but your $A$ has the eigenspace of the whole 2d space and $x$ is in it. I'm speculating that if $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $f(\lambda)$ is a eigenvalue of $A$, and what's the relationship between $A$'s eigenspace and $f(A)$'s eigenspace, does the dimension increased?

Comment: You can always find a non-zero $f$ such that $f(A) = 0$, eg the characteristic polynomial.